# Making an entire styling overwrite another

Tags: css

I have a default a:hover styling however for certain things I have written a separate button class for when I want something to display as a button.

I wish for this:

```
.AeroButtonSlim hover
{
color: #FF0000;
cursor:pointer;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #42C0C4;
opacity: 0.70;
}
```

to override the default one, but I don't want to constantly use the !important feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AeroButtonSlim:hover` not **space**

```
.AeroButtonSlim:hover
{
color: #FF0000;
cursor:pointer;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #42C0C4;
opacity: 0.70;
}
```